# Difference in Cloud Stream App Starters for Rabbit and Kafka based applications

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

There are many out of box application provided by the Spring-Cloud-Steam-App-Starter project.

There are a few URLs provided, based upon some combinations, to import the apps into a Dataflow server instance. I have an understanding that, either stream-applications-kafka-maven or stream-applications-rabbit-maven can be used to import the applications based upon what messaging broker is used with Maven. Is that correct?

But am unsure what happens when apps from both URIs are imported, as the list of apps remains unchanged when that is done so.

Can any one help me understand what happens internally when apps from both URIs are imported, and does that affect the applications in any manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URIs you used to import these apps are for ease of use and help you get started quickly. All you need to do is to rename these apps (that have rabbit, kafka as binders) to differentiate as the name of the `app` which needs to be unique.

You can create your own descriptor file and import them using `app import`.
For more information on how to import custom file, you can refer [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-dataflow-register-apps)

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Ilayaperumal. I believe a differentiated names of these apps coming straight from this starter project could be helpful for developers. I will make the change in my local file and import as you suggested for now.